# I am Creating lightning action button with popup working fine ( i added Firefox steps) but i want automatically

Tags: lightning-aura-components

**I added fallow steps**

**Mozilla Firefox**

```
1. Click on Firefox button on the upper right > Options > Options
2. Select the Content Panel.
3. If "Block pop-up windows" is ticked, click on the Exceptions button.
4. Type salesforce.com in the "Address of website:" field, click on Allow, 
then click close.
5. Click OK on the Options window. Restart Mozilla Firefox

its working fine

I want automatically through lightning component or any configuration  It is possible
```

**component code :**

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('sessionId: '+ state +'----' + 
        JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            if (state === "SUCCESS" && response.getReturnValue() != '') {               
                component.set("v.vh", response.getReturnValue());
                window.setTimeout(
                    $A.getCallback(function(){
                        console.log('submit form');
                        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
                        dismissActionPanel.fire();
                        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                        helper.submitVehicleInquiryForm(component);
                    }),1000
                );                  
            }
```

please any one help me

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot programmatically alter your users' web browser's pop-up settings. That's the design intention of pop-up control.

I've never observed Firefox's pop-up blocker to impact Lightning quick action modals, which appears to be what you are working with. If that is your true problem, you should include that context in your question as it may be soluble.

Comment: i have implemented Lighting component for sending the external system .If User clicks the "Integration" custom lightning button on opportunity detail page then it's redirect to external system (here automatically authentication is completed because we are sending the username, password and action url of external system)

Comment: at the time  getting this error : NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Error in $A.getCallback() [[Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: https://test--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/Je-xU-joOZELy6sVXOpMbQ/aura_prod.js :: value :: line 16"  data: no]]

Comment: Please edit your question to add these details. The fundamental answer doesn't change, though; you still can't alter your users'browser settings.